# Scaler Variable Issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

What I'm trying to do is get a Review Page of a Ordering System to grab data from a database and change the text of the labels to the corresponding fields in the DB. Obviously I have to have it so that it only uses the current logged in users username not the first one in the DB (I'm using the asp.net membership database).

Here is the code from the page behind (I want it to display on-load):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username1 = User.Identity.Name;
   CheckUser.InsertParameters.Add("@username", username1);
   string readsql = 
      "SELECT title, gname, sname, dob, address, suburb, postcode, dayphone, email " +
        "FROM users WHERE username = @username";
   using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
   {
       myConnection.Open();
       SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(readsql, myConnection);
       SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
       myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       reader.Read();

       Label2.Text = reader["title"].ToString();
       Label3.Text = reader["gname"].ToString();
       Label4.Text = reader["sname"].ToString();
       Label5.Text = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("dob")).ToString();
       Label6.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
       Label7.Text = reader["suburb"].ToString();
       Label18.Text = reader["postcode"].ToString();
       Label8.Text = reader["dayphone"].ToString();
       Label9.Text = reader["email"].ToString();

       reader.Close();
       myConnection.Close();
   }
```

And this is the ASPX page itself:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CheckUser" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings: Database %>" 
     SelectCommand ="SELECT title, gname, sname, dob, address, suburb, postcode, dayphone, email FROM users WHERE username = @username" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database.ProviderName %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I've tried so many variations of this but nothing seems to work. Keep getting Scaler Variable error for @username.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: add exact error or exception to the question

Comment: If you use SQLDataSource, you should use data binding on your Labels. If you use SQLCommand, you should pass values of a parameter @username to SQLCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..Add your username1 value

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(readsql, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username1);
// myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); ------> remover this
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string username1 = User.Identity.Name;

        string readsql = "SELECT title, gname, sname, dob, address, suburb, postcode, dayphone, email FROM users WHERE username = @username";
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {    
            myConnection.Open();    
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(readsql, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username1);
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if(reader.Read())
            {
               Label2.Text = reader["title"].ToString();
               Label3.Text = reader["gname"].ToString();
               Label4.Text = reader["sname"].ToString();
               Label5.Text = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("dob")).ToString();
               Label6.Text = reader["address"].ToString();
               Label7.Text = reader["suburb"].ToString();
               Label18.Text = reader["postcode"].ToString();
               Label8.Text = reader["dayphone"].ToString();
               Label9.Text = reader["email"].ToString();
          }
            reader.Close();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: That does seem to work, but now I'm getting a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." but I think thats due to the ordering of the code. I'll have a fiddle with it. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Fixed it, simply had to delete the  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Thankyou everyone for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @Zooch84 updated use  `if(reader.Read())` it will help you.cheers

Answer (score 2):

try to pass parameter by using

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@username").Value = username1;
```